# How much cooler space is required for transporting an elk?

Tags: united-states, hunting, elk

In going on an elk hunt, how much space do I need to store the quarters and meat for transportation home?  Obviously this depends on the size of the animal but how much cooler space should I plan on?

Comment: even when restricting to north american elks, there are several subspecies, and with the difference between males and females it means you can be looking at a range of 1-4x the weight, so that's a bit broad, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Your going to want to debone it to pack it most efficiently into the coolers, otherwise the quarters are going to be too big and awkward to fit into the coolers and they are really heavy.

Once deboned, place 20-25 lbs of meat into double bagged garbage bags for easier handling.

From experience, something like a single 150 to 200 quart cooler will be enough, but you won't be able to lift the cooler. If you got two coolers it would probably take two full size adults to lift them. You could also put the bags in and take them out one at a time for easier handling.

Answer (score 0):

Per this video, it is recommended to have about 170 qts (160.88 litres) of cooler space for one elk.

[How Many Coolers to Get Your Elk Home, Randy Newberg explains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Yt7WL87Cng)?

You can also use a medium sized freezer in your trailer instead of buying coolers.  A cow elk filled up just about half of a 10 cu ft (0.28m cubed) freezer and kept things cool just fine.  This also allows you to hook up a generator to it in case you have issues with getting ice.